# List all the application currently running, ram usage and running time

Tags: android

App RAM usage picture:

[image]

Any code that can link to `Setting -> Apps -> Running`? or any code that can list out all the application that currently running in the phone like this? Currently using android studio , trying to develop app that can show the ram usage of apps and time use

Comment: any research made for the task you have?

Comment: Why is there a javascript tag on this?

Comment: I didn't understand what did you asking, but I didn't not made any research on it but i do look for the problem through search, somehow it doesn't exist the way to call this thing out, hope i answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the Intent for opening the tab of "Running" apps directly
[android common intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html)

However, closest you can get is the apps settings by using this intent `ACTION_APN_SETTINGS`

example:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS);
```

Comment: ACTION_APN_SETTINGS is too far from what i want, ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS is the closest that i need, your link android common intent help me, Thx